# Converting a CGRect to an NSValue in an Array and vice versa

Tags: iphone, nsarray, cgrect

I have an array, full of CGRects.  That part is fine.  The problem is when I go to retrieve the CGRects from the array, I'm getting weird errors.  Check out my code.

```
NSArray *frameLocations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(20, 20, 121, 124)],
                           [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(176, 20, 121, 124)],
                           nil];
```

Than I get the frame in a for loop, like this:

```
 CGRect *imageFrame = [[frameLocations objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue];
```

I've tried a bunch of different variations, spreading that line out over multiple variables.  But I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
CGRect imageFrame = [[frameLocations objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue];
```

You get an actual CGRect back, not a pointer to a CGRect, because it's a primitive C-style type, not an Objective-C object.

Apart from that your code looks correct.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb.  Thanks a lot.  That really helps me.

Comment: Don't feel dumb — the truth of the matter is that what's a C-style primitive and what's an Objective-C object is often just a pragmatic, performance-related decision. You'll get a feel for which is which over time but there's no inherent difference in naming conventions or anything like that, so it's easy to confuse the two things at first.

Comment: Yeah, they should have called it Subjective-C.